# How to call a function inside other function while doing ssh on remote machine using EOF?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scripting, eof

So, I'm trying to call a function on a remote machine using EOF in bash.
Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
other_func() {
c='This is it';
echo $c;
}
test_func() {
a='this is some random string'
ssh -i "somepemkey.pem" ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx << EOF
b='some random sting inside remote server';
echo $a;
echo \$b;
other_func
EOF
}
test_func
```

So, now I get this error: `other_func: command not found`.

I don't want to create a file and put a function in it and then copy it in the remote machine and then call it there. 
I also don't want to put my function inside `here document`.

In the above example variables in the local machine can be called in the remote machine, so how can I call a local function in a remote machine?

Why doesn't EOF understand a function call in a remote machine?

So, I got it resolved by adding this line `"$(declare -f other_func); export -f other_func"` just after ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: @Cyrus corrected the question

Comment: Try to move your function `other_func()` in your here-doc code.

Comment: @Cyrus You want to move the `other_func()` in some other file and then pass it in `EOF`?

Comment: EOF isn't really a term here; you can use any terminator you like after `<<` and the construct is called a "here document".

Comment: Got you @tripleee That is not possible, as the functionality will only be on the server from which it is ran.

Comment: So, I got it resolved by adding this line `"$(declare -f other_func); export -f other_func"` just after ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx.

Comment: I trust you mean `$(declare -f other_func)`. The `export -f` should not be necessary unless you need to use the function in subshells within the `ssh` sesion.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, you are right, I need to use it in sub shell.

Comment: I shudder to think that somebody else, or you yourself, will need to understand your code one day.

Comment: we use comments for understanding the code and this is basic use case. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the remote shell created by `ssh` has no access to variables or functions created on the machine where you run `ssh`, any more than it can read files on the server where you run `ssh` from within that `ssh` session. Anything local you want to make available on the remote machine needs to be copied there, one way or another.

With a function which you *only* need to execute on the remote machine, trivially put it in the here document.

```
ssh user@remote  <<____EOF
    other_func() {
        c='This is it'
        # backslash required inside here doc
        # quoting should be fixed outside here doc, too
        echo "\$c"
    }
    other_func
____EOF
```

For a function you want both locally and remotely, maybe put it in a separate file and copy it over somehow.

```
# make func available locally
. path/to/func_def

ssh user@remote <<____EOF
    # make func available remotely
    $(cat path/to/func_def)
    # and call it
    other_func
____EOF
```

Inlining the function like this is pretty obscure, though; perhaps better to simply `scp` the file to a standard location on every server where you need it.

Comment: This is the easy way to put it inside a file and make it available, but the variables can be taken inside EOF in remote machine, so functions must do the same. I cannot create the function inside the EOF, because of the functionality is in the server from which it is being ran.

Comment: I don't understand this comment; it looks like English but the words don't really seem to fit together. Do you think you could update your question with a more detailed account of your constraints?

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope this becomes more clear.